# Unable to link lib when running go test with .swigcxx

Tags: c++, testing, go, swig

I'm trying to link against a C++ file using SWIG but I've hit a stumbling block.

I've got the following files:

```
foo.cpp
foo.h
fooParser.cpp
fooParser.h
foo.swigcxx
foo_test.go
```

I can run `go build` and `go install` just fine, but when I try to run `go test` I get a bunch of linker errors similar to

```
/tmp/go-build806262998/github.com/foo/_test/_obj_test/foo.cpp.o: In function `foo::FooParser::parseX()':./FooParser.cpp:138: undefined reference to `foo::Foo<std::string>::Foo(std::string const&)'


collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l: running g++ failed: unsuccessful exit status 0x100
```

foo.swigcxx

```
%module foo
%{
#include "foo.h"
#include "fooParser.h"
%}

%include "std_string.i"

%include "foo.h"
%include "fooParser.h"

%template(FooString) Foo<std::string>;
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef _H_Foo
#define _H_Foo

#include<string>

namespace foo {
  template <class T>
  class Foo
  {
  public:
      Foo(const T &initValue = T());
  ...
  };
}
```

fooParser.h

```
#ifndef _H_FooParser
#define _H_FooParser

#include "foo.h"
#include <string>

class FooParser 
{
  public:
  ...
  Foo<std::string> *parse(const std::string &x) throw (Error);
  ...
  private:
     Foo<std::string> *parseX() throw(Error);
  ...
};
```

Why does it complain that it can't find `foo::Foo<std::string>::Foo(std::string const&)` when I have `%template(FooString) Foo<std::string>;`

Comment: You might have better luck getting a response if you include the exact command you ran and the resulting error in your question.

Comment: I encounter the same problem.